# How to gain access to Azure Preview service in Microsoft Commercial or Government cloud in USA

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-gov

I noticed that not all preview features are available while searching the preview service under All Service in Azure portal.

E.g. I was trying to evaluate Event Grid in the US Gov Cloud. I registered the service under my subscription, and then searched it under all services. But I could not find it.

Do I have to wait for sometime for this preview service to show up after I register it under my subscription?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Azure support. Nothing that can be answered here.

Comment: Feature roadmaps are not going to be published or discussed here, and really, aside from guessing, there's no way to tell what features will end up in which regions, whether in the public cloud, gov cloud, Germany, or China.

Comment: Please read my question again. I am not asking the timeline. I understand its the cloud service provider's prerogative and maturity timeline.  What I am asking is why some services (which are in preview) are accessible where as some not? In general if a service is a preview service, is it available for use  (in a region that it is in preview) ? May be it takes some time for a preview service to become available in one's subscription after registering it under subscription ?Specifically if it was never used or for first time use ...that's what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Ah - yeah, if you sign up for a preview service, sometimes it takes time to be granted access. Could be days, could be a month. Really depends on the rollout schedule, available capacity, etc. You can always reach out via support ticket to inquire, or to an account rep if you're working with someone, but really there's nothing else that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product roadmap for Azure Government will appear [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=all).

Only services that have been GA'd in Azure public will be considered for being brought into Azure Government.

Currently Event Grid in Azure Government is CLI only (portal support coming) so [these examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cli-samples) will work. Additionally, not all Event Grid topics are available yet. To see which topics are currently available in Azure Government, run this CLI command (after logging in to Azure Gov via your CLI session):

```
az eventgrid topic-type list -o table
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. So if a certain service is in preview then it is considered to be available using CLI (by default) even if portal is not supported ?

Comment: Not necessarily. When we bring a service in as Preview to Azure Gov, sometimes there is portal support immediately - sometimes it's CLI only - it depends on the team bringing in the service.